# Windows Code signing on multiple computers

Tags: c#, windows-8, visual-studio-2013, code-signing

I'm building a C# wpf .net 4.0 application in Visual Studio 2013 that I plan to release on a website for download on the internet.

I understand that with Windows 8 in order to get rid of all the warnings when users download your application from the internet you have to sign it.  In addition, they recommend the best signing is extended validation code signing (EV signing).  It seems like there's no other option besides EV Code signing or normal code signing (and building reputation) in order to have your application not look like Malware to the users.  I had a question regarding this:

- Does code signing (EV or normal) require you to use the same machine when compiling/releasing/signing?  I work on borrowed machines and have no guarantee that I'll be compiling/releasing/signing on the same computer or installation of Visual Studio 2013.
  In other words, is the signature directly associated with a machine and/or registered installation of Visual Studio?

What can I do if I cannot afford a new laptop of my own and install of visual studio 2013?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does code signing (EV or normal) require you to use the same machine when compiling/releasing/signing?

No, but you need the same *private key* to sign from multiple computers.  Usually this is done using a certificate given to you by a trusted source (like VeriSign) to verify that you are who you say you are.  You can use an auto-generated key file that Visual Studio gives you but clients that try to run your app will get a warning that the key does not come from a trusted source.